# virsh attatch-disk failed: no such file or directory

Tags: qemu, kvm, virsh

I'm using `virsh attatch-disk` to add a new device to a running guest under KVM:

```
# virsh attatch-disk <running-guest-id> --source c.raw --target vdb
```

the output is:

```
error: Failed to attach disk
error: Failed to open file 'c.raw': No such file or directory
```

But the new disk file is under the pwd:

```
ls -l
total 26653060
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8312913920 Jan 10 10:25 c.q
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 53687091200 Jan  5 16:50 c.raw
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 10759023104 Jan  6 02:14 c.VHD
```

why virsh open failed?  I browsed libvirtd.log:

```
2017-01-14 15:22:00.954+0000: 2204: error : virStorageFileGetMetadataRecurse:952 : Failed to open file 'c.raw': No such file or directory
2017-01-14 15:22:08.310+0000: 2209: info : remoteDispatchAuthList:2432 : Bypass polkit auth for privileged client pid:1921,uid:0
```

What the log mean?

---

```
virsh --version
0.10.2

qemu-x86_64 -version
qemu-x86_64 version 2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, you **must** use `c.raw`'s Abs path, relative path are not handled by virsh.